# How do I read a HTML String into a JEditorPane/JTextPane?

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane, jeditorpane

Pretty self explanatory, I have a string that is HTML, how do i draw this onto a JEditorPane/JTextPane?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) I mean *besides* effectively asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.

Comment: google, rose india, superuser, this, etc

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
JEditorPane pane=new JEditorPane();
pane.setContentType("text/html");
String data="<table border=\"1\"><tr><td>cell1</td><td>cell2</td></tr></table>";
pane.setText(data);

frame.add(pane);
frame.setSize(200,200);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find an html interpreter if you're trying to put that single string into a pane. However, if you have a separate page that you're dealing with that holds the html, you can use `JTextPane`'s [`setPage(String URL)`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JEditorPanesetPageURLurl.htm) function.